# Deploying Symfony1 project to a Linode with Ubuntu 14.04 shows blank screen

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony-1.4, ubuntu-14.04, linode

I have a working Symfony 1.4 project hosted in Linode VPS with Ubuntu 12.04. For some reasons, I have to upgrade my Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu/Trusty64 14.04. When I uploaded my symfony 1.4 ,it shows me blank screen, I already cleared cache by running php symfony cc in production.I just copied the old Apache2 sites-enabled configuration and .htaccess that works on Ubuntu 12.04

sites-available/mysite.conf

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite/web 
</VirtualHost>
```

and also this is the .htaccesss

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
# getting no_script_name to work
#RewriteBase /

# we skip all files with .something
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
#RewriteRule .* - [L]

# we check if the .html version is here (caching)
RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# no, so we redirect to our front web controller
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

This shows me when I tried Google's Inspect element

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may forget to enable apache2 rewrite module

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Hope it helps